# Isolated engine (doorkeeper) - use helper methods from the main_app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I want my doorkeeper views to use the application layout:

https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Customizing-views

This contains routes and helper methods from the main application.

For the routes, I can prefix main_app to the path but for the helper method I get the following error:

```
undefined method `is_active?' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0xade808c>

<li class="<%= main_app.is_active?("high_voltage/pages", "api") %>"><%= link_to t('developers'), page_path('api') %></li>
```

Why is this? The helper is in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you generated the views and they are placed in `app/views/doorkeeper/**` then the engine still uses doorkeeper controllers.

To fix this, you have to include your helper(s) into the engine's `ApplicationController`. Let's say you have something like this:

#### app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def my_helper
    "hello"
  end
end
```

#### app/views/doorkeeper/applications/index.html.erb

```
<p>
  <%= my_helper %>
</p>
```

This won't work until you include your application helpers into doorkeeper controllers. So in `config/application.rb`:

```
class YourApp::Application < Rails::Application
  config.to_prepare do
    # include only the ApplicationHelper module
    Doorkeeper::ApplicationController.helper ApplicationHelper

    # include all helpers from your application
    Doorkeeper::ApplicationController.helper YourApp::Application.helpers
  end
end
```

this is similar configuration when you want to customize the layout.

Comment: Did the trick, thanks. If you also know how to access applicationcontroller methods like current_user please share :)

Comment: Couldn't find a way to do this yet, but I'll try

Comment: Interesting, I'm also trying to find a way to access `application_controller` methods from my doorkeeper layout.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

A helper method in application_helper.rb would not be a method for main_app.

The main_app variable is an object with a class/module of ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy.

main_app is a helper that gives you access to your application routes. main_app.page_path('api'), for example.

I'm assuming, with doorkeeper, you need to access the path you want; main_app.highvoltage_page_path('api').some_doorkeeper_active_method

This should hopefully, at least, send you in the right direction, see also:

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#label-Using+Engine%27s+routes+outside+Engine

Good luck.

Comment: The doorkeeper wiki I linked to indicates you can use it on helper methods as well. I already read the rails docs, unfortunately this didn't help me. `main_app.highvoltage_page_path('api').some_doorkeeper_active_method` - not sure what you mean by this but both my main app and the doorkeeper engine should share the same layout. is_active? is a helper method taking two arguments, a controller and action, returning "active" when they match the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question is very old, but I ran into exactly the same problem, and I have a solution. The one requested on Felipe Elias Philipp's answer.

You need to do a little "overwrite". Copy the doorkeepers' engine application_controller.rb file to your app into app/doorkeeper/. Then just change

```
module Doorkeeper 
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

to

```
module Doorkeeper 
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
```

Which now makes doorkeeper use your ApplicationController which probably will have all the methods you need. Together with https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Customizing-views everything works splendidly.